# ddd: Entity or VO

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Suppose I have a `Passenger` object that should contains `Passport` (government id) object. I am getting `Passenger` from `PassengerRepository`. `PassengerRepository` create request to server and obtain data (json) than parse received data and store inside repository.

I have confused because I want to store `Passport` as Entity and put it to `PassportRepository` but all information about password contains inside json than i received above.

I guess that I should use `Passport` as VO and put it inside `Passenger` (aggregate) object. Or I can create a `PassengerService` that will be include `PassengerRepository` and `PassportRepository`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Value objects are objects that are defined by their attributes - two instances with the same attribute values are essentially the same value. If this is correct for your `Passport` type, then it should be a VO.

If it is indeed a VO, then you are sorted - it can only be accessed via the aggregate.

If, however, this is not the case and a passport, in your domain, has an identity that remains constant regardless of attribute changes (someone changes their name, for instance), then you need to think whether, in your domain do `Passport` entities only have meaning when attached to a `Person` or not. If they do only have meaning in this context, then they also should only be accessed via the aggregate.

Comment: Suppose i have identity for a passport (Yes i really have it). Is it good way for creating Service that should contain two repository PassengerRepository and PassportRepository. And this is domain service or application. Thx.

Comment: @tikhop - Difficult to say. It really depends on the application - it could simply be an entity that is only ever accessed by the `Person` aggregate (which could be using either a service or repository to get `Passport`s).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the Passport is a VO. A person can replace her passport which means a new passport (new serial) is issued. I think the Passport is an entity only for the government as it needs to keep track of each unique entity. For the rest of us, we don't care if the new passport has the same id as the old one. We care about having a valid passport.